# Promises are not resolved in Jasmine using Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a problem with a small karma unit test that should check a simple decryption/encryption service. 
The thing is, if I call the following code "manual" (i.e., within my running angular app) everything is fine and I receive the expected test output:

```
this.encryptDataAsync('Hello World of Encryption','b4b63cd1a64dbef72fefe2eb3e3fc3eb').then((encryptedValue : string) : void => {
    console.log('1',encryptedValue);
    this.decryptDataAsync(encryptedValue,'b4b63cd1a64dbef72fefe2eb3e3fc3eb').then(function(decryptedValue : string) : void{
        console.log('2',decryptedValue);
    });
});
```

As soon as I try to run this Karma/Jasmine unit test

```
describe('simple encryption/decryption', function() {
    var results = '';

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        _cryptoService.encryptDataAsync('ABC','b4b63cd1a64dbef72fefe2eb3e3fc3eb').then(function (encryptedValue){
            console.log('1');

            _cryptoService.decryptDataAsync(encryptedValue,'b4b63cd1a64dbef72fefe2eb3e3fc3eb').then(function(decryptedValue){
                console.log('2');
                results = decryptedValue;
                done();
            });

        });

    });

    it("check results", function(done){
        expect(results).toBe('ABC');
        done();
    }, 3000);
});
```

I never reach console.log('1') nor '2'. I can confirm this while debugging the unit test. However, this is the only unit test that fails in the complete suite, so I guess it won't by a problem with modules, etc.

Is there a general problem with my test case? I would have expected that I can use the then functions to handle my test case and, afterwards, call the done() function to invoke the assertion part.

Update/Edit:
The service uses webcrypto as a library. It is complete independent of angular besides being an angular service (so, no variables on scopes, etc)

Comment: Angular promises are resolved when $scope.$apply() is called. And we have no idea how the service is implemented.

Comment: Does this mean that $q (as an independent angular service) promises are also resolved when I call $scope.apply?
If this is the case, where is the connection between $q.defer(); and $scope?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#differences-between-kris-kowal-s-q-and-q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call scope.apply since "$q is integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in angular, which means faster propagation of resolution or rejection into your models and avoiding unnecessary browser repaints, which would result in flickering UI."